# Se pierde la websession después de utilizar shell

Tags: genexus

Tengo un web component que en el evento refresh ejecuta una procedure que termina ejecutando un exe con shell. Todo funciona, el exe genera un xml sin problema. El problema se nota cuando me voy de esa pantalla que al perder la sesión me envía al Login.

No hay errores en el log de Gx, si encontré errores en el visor de eventos:
Sequence contains no matching element aparece varias veces.

Utilizo Gx17 u9 generando web .net

MasterPage evento Start:

```
&PerInicio = &wSession.Get('PerInicio')

if &PerInicio = ""
    if upper(ContentHolder.Pgmname) <> 'UYO'
        Uyo.Call()
    endif
endif
```

WebPanel evento Refresh:

```
GDListarArchivos.Call(&rutaCertificado,&carpetaEnGoogleDrive,&nombreAplicacion,&SDTGoogleDriveArchivos,&retN,&retMsg)
```

GDListarArchivos:

```
&rutaArchIni = GetTemp.Udp() + "\GoogleDrive_" + GUID.NewGuid().ToString() + ".ini"

&rutaSalida = GetTemp.Udp() + "\GoogleDriveListar_" + GUID.NewGuid().ToString() + ".xml"

do 'armaIni'

&comando = '"' + ObtPathApl.Udp() + '\bin\GoogleDrive\ExecuteGoogleDriveApi.exe" "' + &rutaArchIni + '"'

&ret = shell(&comando,1)

&File.Source = &rutaSalida
&SDTGoogleDriveArchivos.FromXmlFile(&File)
```

En web.config

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" maxRequestLength="2147483647" maxQueryStringLength="2097151" maxUrlLength="1286020" executionTimeout="14400" targetFramework="4.6" requestPathInvalidCharacters="" />
<sessionState timeout="999" cookieSameSite="Lax" />
```

Comment: Hola, como estas? ¿Podrías especificar cuál es el código que estás utilizando en el web panel y en la master para llamar al login? En el web config, ¿estás usando los tags executionTimeout en <httpRuntime> y timeout en <sessionState>?

Answer (score 0):

En Genexus me pasaron la solución. El problema se da porque el programa llamado con shell estaba dentro de la carpeta bin. Moví el programa un nivel más abajo y se solucionó